# Library Database MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, entity-relationship

I am currently designing a database for a library a project for my database class. Below is the ER diagram so you can see the basic formatting of the database:
[image: er diagram]

I have completed all of the requirements of the assignment, so please don't think that I am asking for someone to do my homework. What I am asking for assistance with is an idea. We can add extra features into this here such as a report generator, entry form, etc. I have added in a report generator to show the most active member/most popular book and an entry form. But I cannot think of anything else I can add into here to increase the usefulness, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities:

Popularity can be split by gender, which could be interesting.

You could also work on popularity by address to make a geographical analysis, but if this is a local library you probably won't get much out of that.

Another stat that could be worthwile is the average length of borrow.

But the more interesting reports could be those that combine popularity, popularity by gender, average length of borrow with the catalog attributes... so you could have a view by author, by publisher or by publication year.

That is with the current structure. If you were to add genre or media type (book, magazine, CD, DVD) attributes, you would open up a whole lot of new dimensions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ideas, I really like the popularity by gender and avg length of borrow. I will begin to add those in now.